# OrientDB Create GroupBy Table

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2, orientdb-2.1

For example I have following table

```
[id, V1, V2]
[A , 1 , 5]
[A , 2 , 4]
[A , 3 , 3]
[A , 4 , 2]
[B , 9 , 6]
[B , 8 , 7]
[B , 7 , 8]
[B , 6 , 9]
```

I Want to create query with following result

```
[id,     V1`   ,    V2`  ] ]
[A , [1,2,3,4] , [5,4,3,2] ]
[B , [9,8,7,6] , [6,7,8,9] ]
```

OR

```
[id, min , max ]
[A , [1] , [5] ]
[B , [6] , [9] ]
```

How this query can be costructed ? 
I allready tried a lot of options but failed.

Any help will be appriciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select id, $a.V1 as V1, $a.V2 as V2 from <class name>
let $a = (select from <class name> where $parent.current.id = id)
group by id
```

Hope it helps

Regards

Comment: Thanks a lot , it works , this is exactly what i did , i have to say i wanted to put an answer ans saw your solution. This is not a first time that you help me , Thanks

Comment: It has been a pleasure